# jquery Map() is not working on html list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to get an array of the elements inside an html list:

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable ui-sortable">
    <li data-gid="36" class="ui-state-default giftsout" style="height: 90px; overflow-x: hidden;">
        <span style="color: #666; font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;">ITEM1</span>
    </li>
    <li data-gid="37" class="ui-state-default giftsout" style="height: 90px; overflow-x: hidden;">
        <span style="color: #666; font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;">ITEM2</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the JS:

```
console.log($('#sortable1').map(function() { var $item = $(this); return $item.data('gid'); }).get());
```

JSFiffle: http://jsfiddle.net/U4JBg/1/

But so far, im getting a empty array, why?

Comment: Just off-topic here, what's the point in reassigning `$(this)` to `$item` for a short one-liner?

Comment: How is that caching anything when it's a local variable, that's only used once? Or is your actual code longer with more references inside the map?

Comment: Yes is longer, and with more references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to loop the li elements because the `gid` data belongs to the `li` element not in the `ul` element

```
console.log($('#sortable1 li').map(function() { var $item = $(this); return $item.data('gid'); }).get());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2qyp4/)